# Get version from file name

Tags: linux, bash

I'm creating a script that list all the jboss versions. But I was caught in a problem.
Jboss usually has different names for the version.
`jboss-4.0.0.tar.gz`
`jboss-4.0.4.GA.tar.gz`
I managed to obtain the version (for example 4.0.0 or 4.0.4). But I need to obtain all the version 4.0.4.GA
`ls -1 | grep jboss |sed -r 's/^.*-([0-9.]+)\..*/\1/'`
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't parse `ls` output.

`ls` is a tool for interactively looking at file information. Its output is formatted for humans and will cause bugs in scripts. Use `globs` (like I do here) or `find` instead. Understand why: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

```
$ ls -1
jboss-4.0.0.tar.gz
jboss-4.0.4.GA.tar.gz
foobar
```

Using [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) :

```
 $ printf -- '%s\n' * | grep -oP 'jboss-\K.*(?=\.tar\.gz)'
```

Or using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
$ printf -- '%s\n' * | awk -F'jboss-|.tar.gz' '/jboss/{print $2}'
```

Or using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
printf -- '%s\n' * | perl -lne '/jboss-(.*?)\.tar\.gz/ && print $1'
```

### Outputs

```
4.0.0
4.0.4.GA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

for file in jboss-*.tar.gz; do
        [ -f "${file}" ] || continue
        version="${file#*-}"
        version="${version%.tar.gz}"
        echo "${version}"
done
```

Example:

```
$ find
.
./test.sh
./jboss-4.0.0.tar.gz
./jboss-4.0.4.GA.tar.gz

$ ./test.sh
4.0.0
4.0.4.GA
```